An optimization problem involving a symmetric positive definite matrix.
Suppose that A, B are known real symmetric positive definite matrices, P is an unknown real symmetric positive definite matrice, how to solve the following optimization problem?
$$P=\operatorname{argmin}_P \operatorname{tr}\left(A P+B P^{-1}\right)$$
I have proven that the problem is convex with respect to the variable . Clearly, when the dimension of the matrix  is 1, the problem has an analytical solution. I wonder whether the problem can be solved analytically or numerically when the dimension of the matrix
 is 2,3,4, or even higher.

The derivative of the cost is $Df(P)H = \operatorname{tr} ((A-P^{-1}BP^{-1})H)$, so if a solution exists then $PAP=B$.

Thanks, in fact, I have already tried the differentiation method, but I still have doubts about it because the equation$PAP=B$ does not necessarily have a solution.

$$PAP=B\implies (A^{1/2}PA^{1/2})^2=A^{1/2}PAPA^{1/2}=A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}\implies P=A^{-1/2}(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})^{1/2}A^{-1/2}.$$

@qiqi It is straightforward to compute a solution.

Thanks, it helps me a lot.

Denoting  $Q=B^{-1/2}PB^{-1/2}$  and considering the polar decomposition of $C=A^{1/2}B^{1/2}=UR$ where $U$ is orthogonal and $R$ positive definite we have
$$\mathrm{trace}(AP+BP^{-1})= \mathrm{trace}(A^{1/2}PA^{1/2}+B^{1/2}P^{-1}B^{1/2})=\mathrm{trace}(CQC^T+Q^{-1})=\mathrm{trace}(RQR+Q^{-1}).$$ The differential of $Q\mapsto (RQR+Q^{-1})$ is $H\mapsto RHR-Q^{-1}HQ^{-1}$ and is zero for $Q=R^{-1}$ or $P=B^{1/2}R^{-1}B^{1/2}.$
Finally $P\mapsto \mathrm{trace}(AP+BP^{-1})$ is a strictly convex function. To see this, we can ignore the linear function $\mathrm{trace}(AP)$ and observe that the second differential of $Q\mapsto \mathrm{trace}\,Q^{-1}$ is $$H\mapsto \mathrm{trace}(Q^{-1}HQ^{-1}HQ^{-1})=\mathrm{trace}(Q^{-1/2}(Q^{-1/2}HQ^{-1/2})^2Q^{-1/2})> 0$$ if $H\neq 0.$ Since  $Q\mapsto P$ is linear then $P\mapsto BP^{-1}$ is also strictly convex. Therefore $P=B^{1/2}R^{-1}B^{1/2}$ is the minimum of $\mathrm{trace}(AP+BP^{-1}).$
Edit:
Well, you have to understand the definition of the differential of a function $f : E\rightarrow F. $ $$ f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)=A_{x_0}(h)+o(h)$$ Here $h\mapsto A_{x_0}(h)$ is a linear application from $E$ to $F$.  In your particular case $E=F$ is the space of symmetric matrices. $x_0=Q$ fixed, $H\mapsto RHR-Q^{-1}HQ^{1}$ is a linear map from $E$ into itself.  About the absence of trace: we know that $Q\mapsto \mathrm{trace}( RQR+Q^{-1})$ is strictly convex, this implies that its differential can be zero only at most at one point. Composition of the map trace and the map $Q\mapsto RQR+Q^{-1}$ allows to compute its differential $H\mapsto \mathrm{trace}(RHR-Q^{-1}HQ^{-1})$ which is zero on $Q=R^{-1}.$

Thanks for your answer!But I am still confused about some of the details. For example,The differential of  $Q \mapsto\left(R Q R+Q^{-1}\right)$ is $R H R-Q^{-1} H Q^{-1}$ and is zero for $Q=R^{-1}$ or $P=B^{1 / 2} R^{-1} B^{1 / 2}$. What's the meaning of the H here? Why is the trace ignored here?

Thanks for your explanation! It seems that the H you mentioned corresponds to dQ in matrix differentiation.By the way, could you recommend some good references for matrix differentiation？

H=dQ? yes yes yes. Books? I don't know, they have usually  the horrible habit to vectorise the matrices. I learned that  from definitions of differential calculus and practice.

Alright,  I've recently encountered many problems at work that require matrix differentiation. I’ve looked through a lot of resources, but none of them have been very satisfactory. Your method is quite different from the ones I’ve come across in the materials I’ve reviewed. May be similar to the Fréchet derivative in functional analysis?Thanks anyway.

qiqi: gerard can correct me if I'm wrong ( or maybe they convert to vectors ? ) but I think magnus and neudecker should contain material on matrix differentiation. I have the old one but here's the link to the updated version. https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781119541219

qiqi: Note that the authors of the book I linked to are magnus and magnus so the second author changed. Maybe compare the new one to the older one by magnus and neudecker to make sure it's what you want. I don't want to recommend the wrong book.

Thanks,I have downloaded the e-book version of this book(by magnus and neudecker) a few days ago. I'll take some time to read it.
